# How is concurrency in Spring AMQP Listener Container implemented?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

My container XML config:

```
<rabbit:listener-container
        connection-factory="myConnectionFactory"
        acknowledge="none"
        concurrency="10"
        requeue-rejected="false">
    <rabbit:listener ref="myListener" queues="myQueue"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

and `myListener` is just a class

```
@Component("myListener")
public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
    @Autowired
    SomeDependency dependency;
    ....
}
```

I've specified `concurrency="10"` in my XML. What does this mean **exactly**?

---

I've found [some docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html#setConcurrentConsumers%28int%29). They are not that helpful stating:

> Specify the number of concurrent consumers to create. Default is 1.

---

What I am interested in is whether `MyListener` has to be thread safe i.e.

- are there many instances created or single instance used by many threads?
- can I access instance fields w/o synchronization?
- is `SomeDependency dependency`  instantiated once or for each thread/instance?
- does `dependency` need to be thread safe?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, to use concurrency, your listener has to be thread-safe. There is one listener instance per container. However, the `<rabbit:listener-container/>` namespace element is actually just a convenience for adding "shared" attributes, each listener element gets its own container.

It's generally best to use stateless objects (no fields that are written to), but that's not always possible.

If your listener is not thread-safe, you can use...

```
<rabbit:listener-container
    connection-factory="myConnectionFactory"
    acknowledge="none"
    requeue-rejected="false">
    <rabbit:listener ref="myListener" queues="myQueue"/>
    <rabbit:listener ref="myListener" queues="myQueue"/>
    <rabbit:listener ref="myListener" queues="myQueue"/>
    <rabbit:listener ref="myListener" queues="myQueue"/>
    ...
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

...and add `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)`. You will then get a container for each listener and a different instance of the listener will be injected into each.

You will also need prototype scope for any non-thread-safe dependencies injected into the listener.

Comment: I want to be sure I understand correctly: in my example there are 10 `listener-containers`, each holding the one and only `MyListener` instance, correct? In your example there are 10 containers, each with their own listener?

Is it somehow possible to keep my approach (using `concurrency`) and make `Dependency` separate for each `listener-container` ?

Comment: No; in your example there is 1 listener container with 10 consumer threads; in mine there are 10 containers each with one thread. Using prototype scope means each container gets its own instance; so your listener doesn't need to be thread-safe. Without `prototype` scope, each container would get a reference to the same instance - effectively no different (functionally) to your original case. Remember to make all downstream dependencies `prototype` scope too. Like I said, it's generally best to try to make your listener, and its dependencies, stateless to avoid these issues.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now. Stateless classes are really pleasure to work with, but I am afraid I'll have a pretty statefull one here :-( Maybe a `ThreadLocal` will be the easiest way out

Comment: How would you this configuration using annotations in spring-boot?

Comment: It's better to ask a new question and reference this one rather than using comments. I answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926012/how-to-achieve-concurrency-with-a-non-thread-safe-messagelistener).