# How to Achieve Concurrency With a Non-Thread-Safe MessageListener

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341811/how-is-concurrency-in-spring-amqp-listener-container-implemented) explains how to use prototype scope with `<rabbit:listener-container/>` in Spring AMQP when the listener is not thread-safe.

Another user asked (in a comment) how to configure the same environment using only Java Configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's generally best practice to use stateless beans for listeners but when that's not possible, to configure `@Prototype` scope listener (and multiple containers) using only Java Configuration, you can use:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container1() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames("test.mismatch");
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener()));
    container.setMismatchedQueuesFatal(true);
    return container;
}

...

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer containerN() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames("test.mismatch");
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener()));
    container.setMismatchedQueuesFatal(true);
    return container;
}

@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public MyNotThreadSafeListener listener() {
    return new MyNotThreadSafeListener();
}
```

Remember that any dependencies injected into `MyNotThreadSafeListener` must also be prototype beans.

Bottom line is stateless beans are best.