# how to avoid too many connections(TCP) in rabbitMQ using spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tcp, rabbitmq

Q: when messages(30,000+) flood in, the consumer server established too many TCP , even more than 10,000 .how to configer in spring to avoid that?!

**listener:**
[image]

**sendMQ**
[image]

**the following is rabbitmq.xml**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to So, avoid putting screenshot of code instead of pasting them directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This stackoverflow question might help: [How is concurrency in Spring AMQP Listener Container implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341811/how-is-concurrency-in-spring-amqp-listener-container-implemented)

Quick excerpt, see 'concurrency':

> ```
> <rabbit:listener-container
>         connection-factory="myConnectionFactory"
>         acknowledge="none"
>         concurrency="10"
>         requeue-rejected="false">
>     <rabbit:listener ref="myListener" queues="myQueue"/>
> </rabbit:listener-container>
> ```

I am not using the Spring XML configuration, but annotations, but this is what I have used to limit the amount of concurrent consumers:

```
@Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());

        // process each message one at a time
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1);
        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: as I know , listeners use long connection, i send message using short connection to MQ after consuming . Is that right?　If so , it is sending message caused too many TCPs , why need i change the listeners config ?

Comment: @counterFish You have my attempt at an answer above. Give that a try. If it works, great, if not, feel free to comment and say it didn't work for you.